# Proving $\cot(\pi z)$ is bounded on the disk $|z|=R$, $R=N+\frac{1}{2}, N\in\Bbb N^+$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on a proof in complex analysis. One of the steps involves showing that $|\cot(\pi Re^{i\theta})|$ is bounded as $R\to\infty$, and $\theta$ is not fixed. In other words, $|\cot(\pi z)|$ is bounded for $z$ on the disk $|z|=R$, as $R$ tend to infinity. I expanded and reduced the expression to $$|\cot(\pi Re^{i\theta})|=\left|1+\frac{2}{e^{2i\pi Re^{i\theta}}-1}\right|.$$
Please advise on how to proceed.

Comment: Is $\theta$ fixed?

Comment: $\theta$ is not fixed.

Comment: What's the connection with the title ?

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure $\cot$ is necessarily bounded?

Comment: If we set $R=1$, then $\theta=2\Rightarrow |e^{\,\dots}|\approx0.162$ but $\theta=3\Rightarrow |e^{\,\dots}|\approx0.754$ so it's definitely not constant wrt. $\theta$.

Comment: @Jam I don't think you are answering my question

Comment: Sorry, guys, I missed a $\pi$ in my question. Please see the revised question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three cases ($R\to\infty$):

$(1)$ $\enspace \displaystyle 0<|e^{2i\pi e^{i\theta}}|<1 \enspace $ => $\enspace \displaystyle \frac{1}{e^{2i\pi Re^{i\theta}}-1}\to -1\enspace $ => $\enspace |\cot(\pi Re^{i\theta})|\to |1+\frac{2}{-1}|=1$

$(2)$ $\enspace \displaystyle |e^{2i\pi e^{i\theta}}|>1\enspace $ => $\enspace \displaystyle \frac{1}{e^{2i\pi Re^{i\theta}}-1}\to 0\enspace $ => $\enspace |\cot(\pi Re^{i\theta})|\to |1+0|=1$

$(3)$ $\enspace \displaystyle |e^{2i\pi e^{i\theta}}|=1\enspace $ => $\enspace \sin\theta =0 \enspace ;\enspace \displaystyle R:=x+k \enspace $, $\enspace k\in\mathbb{N}\enspace $ with $\enspace k\to\infty$

$\enspace \enspace \displaystyle 0<x_0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}\enspace $ or $\enspace \displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq x_0<1\enspace $ ($0<x_0<1$ has to be choosen)

$\enspace \enspace => \enspace \displaystyle |\frac{1}{e^{2i\pi Re^{i\theta}}-1}|=|\frac{1}{e^{i2\pi x}-1}|\leq |\frac{1}{e^{i2\pi x_0}-1}|$

$\enspace \enspace \displaystyle |\cot(\pi Re^{i\theta})|\leq 1+2|\frac{1}{e^{2i\pi Re^{i\theta}}-1}|\leq 1+2|\frac{1}{e^{i2\pi x_0}-1}|$

$\enspace \enspace$ We have seen here, that the limit depends on the definition of $R$.

$\enspace \enspace$ E.g. $\enspace \displaystyle R:=\frac{1}{2}+k$ , $k\in\mathbb{N} \enspace$ => $\enspace \displaystyle |\cot(\pi Re^{i\theta})|=|1+\frac{2}{-2}|=0$

Answer (score 7):

Let $z=x+iy$.  Then, we can express the magnitude of the cotangent function as

$$\begin{align}
|\cot(z)|&=\left|\frac{e^{i2z}+1}{e^{i2z}-1}\right|\\\\
&=\left|\frac{(1+\cos(2x)e^{-2y})+i\sin(2x)e^{-2y}}{(1-\cos(2x)e^{-2y})-i\sin(2x)e^{-2y}}\right|\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1+2\cos(2x)e^{-2y}+\cos^2(2x)e^{-4y}+\sin^2(2x)e^{-4y}}{1-2\cos(2x)e^{-2y}+\cos^2(2x)e^{-4y}+\sin^2(2x)e^{-4y}}}\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1+e^{-4y}+2\cos(2x)e^{-2y}}{1+e^{-4y}-2\cos(2x)e^{-2y}}}\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\cosh(2y)+\cos(2x)}{\cosh(2y)-\cos(2x)}}\\\\
|\cot(\pi z)|&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sqrt{1+\frac{2\cos(2\pi x)}{\cosh(2\pi y)-\cos(2\pi x)}}} \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Next, suppose $|z|=N+1/2$.  We will analyze the following two cases; (i) $N+1/2\ge |x|\ge N+1/4$ and (ii) $|x|\le N+1/4$.

---

**CASE $1$:**  $\displaystyle N+\frac12\ge |x|\ge N+\frac14$

For $N+\frac12\ge |x|\ge N+1/4$, we see that $\cos(2\pi x)\le 0$.  Therefore, since $\cosh(2\pi y)\ge 1$ and $\cos(2\pi x)\le 1$, we find that

$$-1\le\frac{2\cos(2\pi x)}{\cosh(2\pi y)-\cos(2\pi x)}\le 0$$

whence we have from $(1)$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{|\cot(\pi z)|\le 1} \tag 2$$

for $N+\frac12\ge |x|\ge N+1/4$.

---

**CASE $2$:**

For $|x|\le N+1/4$, we find the following lower bound for $\cosh(2\pi y)$ by using the asymptotic relationship $\cosh(x)=1+\frac12 x^2+O(x^4)$.  Therefore, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\cosh(2\pi y)&\ge 1+\frac12(2\pi y^2)\\\\
&=1+2\pi^2 ((N+1/2)^2-x^2)\\\\
&\ge 1+2\pi^2 ((N+1/2)^2-(N+1/4)^2)\\\\
&\ge 1+3\pi^2/8
\end{align}$$

whence we have from $(1)$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{|\cot(\pi z)|\le \sqrt{1+\frac{16}{3\pi^2}}< 1.24 } \tag 3$$

for $|x|\le N+1/4$.

---

> Putting $(2)$ and $(3)$ together, we have the uniform bound for $|\cot(\pi z)|$ for $|z|=N+1/2$ is

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{|\cot(\pi z)|\le 1.24}$$

for all $|z|=N+1/2$

And we are done!

Comment: Would you please briefly explain, how did you approach the fact that $$|\cot{\pi z}|=\sqrt{\frac{\cosh{2\pi y}+\cos{2\pi x}}{\cosh{2\pi y}-\cos{2\pi x}}}$$?

Comment: @MichalDvořák I've edited the answer to address your comment.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer further.