# Contour integration problem, proving complex function is bounded

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, contour-integration, upper-lower-bounds

I've got a complex function:
$$f(z)=\frac{\pi\cot{\pi z}}{z^2}$$
I want to integrate it around a contour $\Gamma_N$ such that the poles at $$-N,-N+1,-N+2\cdots-1,0,1,\cdots N-2, N-1, N$$ are contained in the contour, so i choose a circle with radius $N+\varepsilon$ where $N\in\Bbb{N}, \varepsilon \in (0,1)$
[image: The contour]

My goal is to show that the integral for $N\to\infty$
$$\oint_{\Gamma_N}f(z)dz=0$$
In fact, it must equal to zero because by residue theorem
$$\oint_{\Gamma_N}f(z)dz=\operatorname{Res}(f,0)+\sum_{n=-N,n\neq0}^Nn^{-2}$$
the residuum at $0$ is equal to $-\pi^2/3$ and for $N\to\infty$ this solves the basel problem. Returning to the contour integral:
$$\oint_{\Gamma_N}f(z)dz=\int_0^{2\pi}f((N+\varepsilon)e^{i\varphi})d(N+\varepsilon)e^{i\varphi}=$$
$$=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\pi\cot({\pi(N+\varepsilon)e^{i\varphi})}}{(N+\varepsilon)e^{i\varphi}}id\varphi$$
Now i would prove that the limit as $N\to\infty$ of the integrand goes to zero, namely:
$$\mathcal L= \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\cot{(\pi(N+\varepsilon))}}{(N+\varepsilon)}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\cos{(\pi(N+\varepsilon))}}{(N+\varepsilon)\sin{(\pi(N+\varepsilon)})}$$
and the argument is: $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\cos{(N+\varepsilon)}} {N+\varepsilon}=0$$ by squeeze theorem and $$\sin(\pi(N+\varepsilon))$$ is never equal to zero, because $$(N+\varepsilon)\notin\Bbb{N}$$ This would prove that integrand is zero therefore the contour integral is equal to zero. My question is, is my argument correct? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The argument is not valid.  You need to show that $\frac{\cot((N+1/2)e^{i\phi})}{(N+1/2)}\to 0$.  So, you need to analyze more carefully the behavior of the complex cotangent on the circle.

Comment: So, i used the definition of cotangent: $$\cot{z}=i\frac{e^{2iz}+1}{e^{2iz}-1}$$ and obtained an integral where the numerator is a fraction of the form $$\frac{e^{2i\pi(N+\varepsilon)\cos{\varphi}}e^{-2\pi(N+\varepsilon)\sin{\varphi}}+1}{e^{2i\pi(N+\varepsilon)\cos{\varphi}}e^{-2\pi(N+\varepsilon)\sin{\varphi}}-1}$$ this entire thing in absolute value, can i now say that the part with $e^{i...}$ doesn't change the value and $$e^{-2\pi...}$$ is bounded and for $N\to\infty$ goes to zero?

Comment: Not quite.  See [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958026/proving-cot-pi-z-is-bounded-on-the-disk-z-r-r-n-frac12-n-in-bbb/1958878#1958878) where I showed that the magnitude of the cotangent function, $|\cot(z)|$ is bounded on the circle $|z|=N+1/2$.

Comment: This helps, but just one clarification, how did you come to the fact, that... $$|\cot{\pi z}|=\sqrt{\frac{\cosh{2\pi y}+\cos{2\pi x}}{\cosh{2\pi y}-\cos{2\pi x}}}$$

Comment: Please see the edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958026/proving-cot-pi-z-is-bounded-on-the-disk-z-r-r-n-frac12-n-in-bbb/1958878#1958878), I showed that for $|z|+N+1/2$, the magnitude of the complex cotangent function, $|\cot(z)|$, satisfies the bound

$$|\cot(z)|=\sqrt{\frac{\cosh(2y)+\cos(2x)}{\cosh(2y)-\cos(2x)}}\le \sqrt{1+\frac{16}{3\pi^2}}$$

Hence, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\,\oint_{|z|=N+1/2} \frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z^2}\,dz\,\right|&\le \oint_{|z|=N+1/2}\frac{\pi |\cot(z)|}{|z|^2}\,|dz|\\\\
&\le \,2\pi (N+1/2)\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt{1+\frac{16}{3\pi^2}}}{(N+1/2)^2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{2\pi^2\sqrt{1+\frac{16}{3\pi^2}}}{N+1/2}
\end{align}$$

which approaches $0$ as $N\to \infty$.

Finally, using the residue theorem we find that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ne 0}\frac1{n^2}=-\text{Res}\left(\frac{\pi \cot(\pi z)}{z^2}, z=0\right)&=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\left(\pi z\cot(\pi z)\right)\\\\
&=-\frac12\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\left(\frac{1-\frac12(\pi z)^2+O(\pi z)^4}{1-\frac16(\pi z)^2+O(\pi z)^4}\right)\\\\
&=-\frac12\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\left(1-\frac13 (\pi z)^2+O(\pi z)^4\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{3}
\end{align}$$

---

**Appendix**:

In this appendix we address the question that the OP asked in a comment regarding the equality $|\cot(z)|=\sqrt{\frac{\cosh(2y)+\cos(2x)}{\cosh(2y)-\cos(2x)}}$.  Proceeding we have

$$\begin{align}
|\cot(z)|&=\left|\frac{e^{i2z}+1}{e^{i2z}-1}\right|\\\\
&=\left|\frac{(1+\cos(2x)e^{-2y})+i\sin(2x)e^{-2y}}{(1+\cos(2x)e^{-2y})-i\sin(2x)e^{-2y}}\right|\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1+2\cos(2x)e^{-2y}+\cos^2(2x)e^{-4y}+\sin^2(2x)e^{-4y}}{1-2\cos(2x)e^{-2y}+\cos^2(2x)e^{-4y}+\sin^2(2x)e^{-4y}}}\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1+e^{-4y}+2\cos(2x)e^{-2y}}{1+e^{-4y}-2\cos(2x)e^{-2y}}}\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\cosh(2y)+\cos(2x)}{\cosh(2y)-\cos(2x)}}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: I got the part with the residue myself already, was just looking to prove the boundeness of the cotangent function, which is practically in the answer you posted a link to, anyways, asked for a brief explanation here.

Comment: @MichalDvořák I edited to address the question you had asked in a comment under your posted question.  Let me know if you have any further questions.  Really hope all of this helped.

Comment: I see it now, deleted it, because i realised it fast enough, i was blind. I guess im done with the part for $|\cot{\pi z}|$, gonna now focus on the proof of boundeness part.

Comment: Sounds as if you're making good progress.  Pleased to hear.

Comment: And feel free to up vote both this and the referenced question and accept this answer, all as you see fit.

Comment: Got stuck on the third (fourth) line again :/ what do i factor out to get the $\cosh{2y}$ in there? namely expression:
$$\sqrt{\frac{1+e^{-4y}+2\cos{(2x)}e^{-2y}}{...}}$$

Comment: Multiply numerator and denominator by $\frac12 e^{2y}$.

Comment: Great! Ok, now just to be sure, i don't have to explore the case 2, where you prove that  $|\cot{\pi z}|$ is bounded by $1,24$. It should be enough when i show that $|\cot{\pi z}|\le 1$ and therefore say that my integrand goes to zero, is that correct?

Comment: No, you need to show that it is bounded on the circle.

Comment: I see, well, this is going to take me some more time and will leave it for another day i guess. Anyways, i might reconsider choosing the path of integration, i think, if i choose the contour to be rectangle with bounds $N+\varepsilon,-N-\varepsilon$ it might be easier to prove that it goes to zero with $N\to\infty$... anyways, thanks for clarifications and help, i apreciate it, i still have lot to learn about complex analysis.

Comment: @MichalDvořák Don't give up.  You're almost there.  In my referenced answer, I showed that $|\cot(z)|$ is bounded on the circle $|z|=N+1/2$.

Comment: I'm struggling with the part of the proof that $|\cot{\pi z}|$ is bounded. I got the first part (the Case 1). We show that $|\cot{\pi z}|$ is bounded above by $1$ in the strip $N+1/4\le|\operatorname{Re}(z)|\le N+1/2$. That is 100% clear to me

Comment: Okay, to the line where you say: $$\cosh(2\pi y) \ge 1+\frac{1}{2}(2\pi y^2)$$ that's just fine,...and then say that's equal to $$1+2\pi ^2((N+1/2)^2-x^2)$$ Isn't there a typo or am i missing something? By the way, where did this $x^2$ come from :S?

Comment: For the other part, we are on the circle $|z|+N+1/2$ for $|x|\le N+1/4$.  We can find a lower bound for $\cosh(2y)$ on that part of the circle.  We can choose to use the crude estimate $\cosh(2\pi y)\ge 1+\frac12 (2\pi y)^2$.  But recall $x^2+y^2=(N+1/2)^2$ and so $y^2=(N+1/2)^2-x^2\ge (N+1/2)^2-(N+1/4)^2= \frac12N+\frac3{16}\ge \frac3{16}$.

Comment: Okay, got that part, now how do i exactly return back to the (1) equation (as you reference it) because for $|x| \le N+1/4$ we do not have any bounds set for $\cos{2\pi x}$

Comment: Michael, we always have $|\cos(2\pi x)|\le 1$.

Comment: Ah, yes, forgot about that, true. Seems like i have it. Just for clarification, because this way of proof seems really weird to me. First, we proved that in the vertical strip where $N+1/4 \le \operatorname{Re}(z) \le N+1/2$ the cotangent function is bounded. In the second step, by setting some other bound for cosh, we found, that in the rest of the plane, that means for $ N+1/4\ge \operatorname{Re}(z)$ we found that the cotangent is bounded by this weird transcendental number, which is approximately 1,24. Therefore we proved that cotangent is bounded on the entire circle. Am i right?

Comment: Yes!  You have it now.  Well done.

Comment: Thanks, may i also ask about the limit, as you solved it. I personally went through the second derivative and got to same result after some trigonometric limit. I haven't really come across this big O notation. I just know that it means something like "we don't care about those terms". But how do you get from $$\lim\bigg(\frac{1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+...}{1-\frac{1}{6}x^2+...}\bigg)$$ to $$\lim \bigg(1-\frac{1}{3}x^2\bigg)$$?

Comment: Michael, note that $\frac1{1-t}=1+t+t^2+\cdots=1+t+O(t^2)$.  So, $\frac{1}{1-\frac13 x^2+O(x^4)}=1+\frac13x^2+O(x^4)$

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{\Im\left(z\right) \to \pm\infty}\left\vert\cot\left(z\right)\right\vert = 1$ and $\displaystyle\left\vert\oint_{\left\vert z\right\vert = R}{\mathrm{d}z \over z^{2}}\right\vert \sim
{2\pi \over R}$ as $\displaystyle R \to \infty$.