# Contour Integral Involving $e^z$, a Semicircle, and Triangle Inequality

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers, contour-integration

For context, part of this comes from a real improper integral I am trying to solve, which I am not entirely sure if I am even going in the right direction. But anyways, I am trying to evaluate

$$\oint_Cf(z)dz = \int_{-R}^{-\epsilon}f(z)dz + \int_{\gamma}f(z)dz + \int_{\epsilon}^{R}f(z)dz + \int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz,$$

where $C$ is a large semicircle of radius $R$, $\gamma$ is a small indented circular path of radius $\epsilon$ above $z=0$, and $\Gamma$ is the circumference above the real axis. I let

$$f(z) = \frac{e^{4z}-e^{2z}}{z(e^{2z}+1)^3}.$$

I can figure out how to deal with all the other integrals with no problem including the singularities, except for the integral over $\Gamma$. Basically, I'm trying to prove that

$$\lim_{R \to \infty}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{e^{4z}-e^{2z}}{z(e^{2z}+1)^3}dz = 0$$

by proving that

$$\lim_{R \to \infty}\left|\int_{\Gamma}\frac{e^{4z}-e^{2z}}{z(e^{2z}+1)^3}dz\right| = 0$$

and using the Squeeze Theorem.

Here is my work so far:

$$
\eqalign{
\left|\int_{\Gamma}\frac{e^{4z}-e^{2z}}{z\left(e^{6z}+3e^{4z}+3e^{2z}+1\right)}dz\right| &\leq \left|\frac{e^{4z}-e^{2z}}{z\left(e^{6z}+3e^{4z}+3e^{2z}+1\right)}\right|\left(\pi R\right) \cr
&= \frac{\left|e^{4z}-e^{2z}\right|}{\left|z\right|\left|e^{6z}+3e^{4z}+3e^{2z}+1\right|}\left(\pi R\right) \cr
&= \frac{\left|e^{4z}-e^{2z}\right|}{R\left|e^{6z}+3e^{4z}+3e^{2z}+1\right|}\left(\pi R\right) \cr
&= \frac{\pi\left|e^{4z}-e^{2z}\right|}{\left|e^{6z}+3e^{4z}+3e^{2z}+1\right|} \cr
&\leq \frac{\pi\left(e^{4R}+e^{2R}\right)}{\left|e^{6z}+3e^{4z}+3e^{2z}+1\right|}, 
}
$$

where I used the inequality $\left|e^z\right| \leq e^R$. I got that from (and if someone can check if this is correct then that would be great)

$$\eqalign{
\left|e^z\right| &= \left|e^{Re^{i\theta}}\right| \cr
&= \left|e^{e^{i\theta}}\right|^R \cr
&= \left|e^{\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}}\right|^R \cr
&= \left|e^{\cos{\theta}}\right|^R \cdot \left|e^{i\sin{\theta}}\right|^R \cr
&= \left|e^{\cos{\theta}}\right|^R \cr
&\leq e^R,
}
$$
since
$$\eqalign{
-1 \leq \cos{\theta} &\leq 1 \cr
e^{-1} \leq e^{\cos{\theta}} &\leq e^1 \cr
\left|e^{-1}\right| \leq \left|e^{\cos{\theta}}\right| &\leq \left|e^1\right| \cr
\left|e^{\cos{\theta}}\right| &\leq e \cr
\left|e^{\cos{\theta}}\right|^R &\leq e^R. \cr
}
$$

**Question**: How exactly can I deal with the bottom such that I can easily take the limit as $R$ goes to infinity? I want to make the bottom smaller and I tried using the fact that if $z$ is on $C$ then $|z| = R$. What I tried was using the Reverse Triangle Inequality to get that

$$\left|e^{2z}+1\right|^3 = \left|e^{2z}+1\right| \cdot \left|e^{2z}+1\right| \cdot \left|e^{2z}+1\right| \geq \left|\left|e^{2z}\right|-|1|\right| \cdot \left|\left|e^{2z}\right|-|1|\right| \cdot \left|\left|e^{2z}\right|-|1|\right| = \left|\left|e^{2z}\right|-|1|\right|^3,$$

but I don't know a way to express that last expression in terms of $R$. Intuitively, it "seems" like the denominator gets bigger faster than the numerator as the radius gets larger and larger. (I feel like I am just overthinking it and that this should be a lot easier than I expected.)

Comment: $z=iR$ belongs to $\Gamma$, can you see that $|e^{6z}+3e^{4z}+3e^{2z}+1|$ at $z=iR$  is less or equal 8?

Comment: I think, in the numerator you should have written $e^{4R}+e^{2R}$ since you used the triangular inequality. Right?

Comment: @BobDobbs You're right, that was a little error on my part.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral_0%5Einfty+%28e%5E%284z%29-e%5E%282z%29%29%2F%28z%28e%5E%282z%29%2B1%29%5E3%29dz wtf @Accelerator

Comment: Haha! I think it's a pretty interesting result. @BobDobbs

Comment: WolframAlpha is much better than us. This sucks. @Accelerator

Comment: The issue is that there are poles on the imaginary axis at $z=i(2n+1)\pi/2$.  So, set $R=N\pi$ with $N\in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ and let $N\to \infty$.   This way, the semi-circle with radius $N\pi$ is bounded away from the poles.

Comment: There's $\underline{not}$ any singularity at $z = 0$.

Comment: Why not? @FelixMarin

Comment: @Accelerator Because $\lim_{z \to 0}\,\,\,\operatorname{f}\left(z\right) = 1/4$. Moreover, $\operatorname{f}\left(z\right) \sim {1 \over 4} - {z^{2} \over 3}$ as $z \to 0$.

Comment: @FelixMarin I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958026/proving-cot-pi-z-is-bounded-on-the-disk-z-r-r-n-frac12-n-in-bbb/1958878#1958878), I showed that $|\cot(\pi z)|$ is bounded on the circle $|z|=(N+1/2)$ for $N\in \mathbb{N^+}$.  Analogously, it is straightforward to show that $|\tanh(z)|$ is bounded on the circle $N\pi$, $N\in \mathbb{N^+}$.

Let $B$ represent an upper bound of $|\tanh(z)|$ on the circle $N\pi$, $C_N$ be the semi-circular arc with radius $N\pi$ in the upper-half plane, and $I_N=\int_{C_N}\frac{\sinh(z)}{z\cosh^3(z)}\,dz$.  Then we have the estimates on the semi-circular arc of radius $N\pi$

$$\begin{align}
|I_n|&=\left|\int_{C_N}\frac{\sinh(z)}{z\cosh^3(z)}\,dz\right|\\\\
&\le \int_{C_N}\frac{1}{N\pi}\left|\tanh(z)\right|\,\left|\text{sech}^2(z)\right|\,|dz|\\\\
&\le B \int_0^\pi \left|\text{sech}(N\pi e^{i\phi})\right|^2\,d\phi\\\\
&=8B \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{|e^{-N\pi e^{i\phi}}|^2}{|1+e^{-2N\pi e^{i\phi}}|^2}\,d\phi\\\\
&\le \frac{8B}{\inf_{\phi\in[0,\pi], N\in\mathbb{N^+}} {|1+e^{-2N\pi e^{i\phi}}|^2}}\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-2N\pi \cos(\phi)}\,d\phi\\\\
&\le \frac{8B}{\inf_{\phi\in[0,\pi], N\in\mathbb{N^+}} {|1+e^{-2N\pi e^{i\phi}}|^2}}\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-2N\pi (1-2\phi/\pi)}\,d\phi\\\\
&\le \frac{8B}{\inf_{\phi\in[0,\pi], N\in\mathbb{N^+}} {|1+e^{-2N\pi e^{i\phi}}|^2}}\frac{1-e^{-2N\pi}}{4N}
\end{align}$$

which clearly approaches $0$ as $N\to \infty$.

So, by judiciously selecting the radius of the semi-circle to be $N\pi$, we construct a sequence of integrals $I_N$ such that $\lim_{N\to\infty}I_N=0$.

Comment: (+1) It will take me a little bit of time to understand the process, but I greatly appreciate the work you put in. @MarkViola

Comment: @Accelerator Thank you.  Much appreciated.  It was my pleasure.

Comment: I think I can follow the inequality process. I was just trying to prove for myself the other day that $|\tanh{(z)}|$ is bounded by $N\pi$. I have $|\tanh{(z)}| = \sqrt{\frac{\cosh\left(2x\right)-\cos\left(2y\right)}{\cosh\left(2x\right)+\cos\left(2y\right)}}$ and I made a case where $N\pi - \pi/4 \leq |y| \leq N\pi$. Maybe this should be a separate problem, but what would another case be? Or am I going about proving this by cases the right way?

Comment: @Accelerator Please have a look at the answer I posted [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958026/proving-cot-pi-z-is-bounded-on-the-disk-z-r-r-n-frac12-n-in-bbb/1958878#1958878) and referenced with a link in the first sentence of this post.  If you can follow the logic for finding a bound for $|\cot(\pi z)|$, it should be straightforward to adapt it and find a bound for $|\tanh(z)|$.

Comment: Okay. I did read your linked post before and I remember being slightly confused by the cases for some reason, so hastily, I tried to apply your post to find a bound for $|\tanh{(z)}|$. But now, I will read your post very carefully and try to follow the logic first, then I will adapt and apply it. @MarkViola

Comment: Hi @Accelerator That sounds good.  Let me know if there is anything I can help clarify.

Comment: I deleted my answer. Cartesian thinking was not good.