# Contour integral for $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{e^{2z}}{\cosh(e^z)}$

Tags: residue-calculus, catalans-constant

By substituting $u=e^{e^x}$ in the Catalan's constant C's integral $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\ln u}{u^2+1}du=C$, I obtained the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\frac{e^{2x}}{\cosh(e^x)}$.

Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{e^{2z}}{\cosh(e^z)}$. I want to evaluate the integral of this function around the well-known closed semi-circle lying on the upper half-plane. I need to find the poles and residues of $f(z)$. I found $Z\times Z$ many poles. But then sum of the residues became nonsense.

Wolfram Alpha says no poles: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Residues+e%5E%282z%29%2F%282cosh%28e%5Ez%29%29

What is going on here? Can you help me? I am lost.

Comment: I tried this with a rectangular contour and the function $$f(z)=\frac{z^2}{e^{-z}+e^z}$$ but I have gotten stuck on the Principal Value part of the left side of the rectangular contour.

Comment: I don't know how to solve this off the top of my head, but in my experience, dealing with inequalities involving $e^z$ when integrating the circular part of the contour is a headache. I tried a similar method here if you want to check it out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4509476/contour-integral-involving-ez-a-semicircle-and-triangle-inequality

Comment: But here we have $cosh(e^z)$ not $cosh(z)$... Anyways.

Answer (score 1):

(Okay, this integral made me go on a complex analysis goose chase that eventually trolled me smh with an integral that integrated through an asymptote.)

I've come to the conclusion that complex analysis won't really work here, so let's use series.

We seek to find $$I=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+1}\text{ d}x$$
Performing a change of variables, we have
$$u=\ln(x),\qquad\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}x}=\frac1x,\qquad\text{d}x=x\text{ d}u,\qquad x=e^u$$
$$\implies\int_0^\infty\frac{u\cdot e^u}{e^{2u}+1}\text{ d}u=\int_0^\infty\frac{u}{e^{u}+e^{-u}}\text{ d}u=\int_0^\infty\frac{x\cdot e^{-x}}{1+e^{-2x}}\text{ d}x$$
I just rewrote the $u$ into $x$ at the end just for convenience.

Now let's take a look at the general case where we have
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}\cdot e^{-x}}{1+e^{-2x}}\text{ d}x$$
We can see that
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\cdot\left(\frac{e^{-x}}{1-(-e^{-2x})}\right)\text{ d}x&=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\cdot\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^ne^{-(2n+1)x}\right)\text{d}x\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-(2n+1)x}\text{ d}x\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^s}\cdot\Gamma(s)\\
&=\beta(s)\Gamma(s)
\end{align}
where the first line follows from a geometric series expansion, the second from the definition of the gamma function, and the third from the definition of the Dirichlet beta function.

In our case, we have $s=2$ So $$I=\beta(2)\Gamma(2)$$
In particular, we see that $\Gamma(2)=1!=1$ but more importantly, $\beta(2)=C$ because *by definition* the Catalan constant $C$ is equal to the series representation of the Dirichlet beta function with parameter 2.

Hence we have shown that $$I=\boxed{C}$$

Comment: So you think there is nothing to do in residue approach. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @BobDobbs I tried a few different contours including a pizza slice and rectangular contour, none of them worked, so I'm guessing that a residue based approach may be difficult to achieve. Someone else might be able to idk but i couldnt :(

Comment: Is there an analytic continuation contour integral for DBF similar to RZF?

Comment: @BobDobbs yes sort of. the dirichlet beta function can be expressed in terms of the hurwitz zeta function, which in turn can be expressed as an integral(that would typically be evaluated using a contour. Plus I think you can find the integral representation of the hurwitz zeta function with Laplace transforms)

Comment: They calculated all $\beta(2k)$s by Euler's zigzag numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Dirichlet%20beta,alternating%20character%20of%20period%20four.